# Can not understand this specific CmakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile my first VST plugin. I have taken a [simple VST project from GitHub](https://github.com/gijzelaerr/gijzelijzer) and have tried to break it down and understand it all, rewrite it myself, and then subsequently compile it.

I am currently breaking down the CmakeLists.txt file. I have come upon a line I do not understand.

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gijzelijzer
    ${VSTSDK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I do not know what the VST_LIBRARIES variable is. It is not declared anywhere else in the CmakeList.txt. Is this a broken cmake file, or is there something I don't understand about the syntax that is going on here. I just simple do not understand what is going on here.

```
PROJECT(GIJZELIJZER)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
SET(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE ON)

IF (MSVC)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(/D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
ENDIF()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find 3rd party libs
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET(VSTSDK_PATH ${GIJZELIJZER_SOURCE_DIR}/../vstsdk2.4 CACHE PATH "Path to the Steinberg VST SDK")
SET(VSTSDK_INCLUDE_DIR ${VSTSDK_PATH})
SET(VSTSDK_PLUGIN_SOURCE
    ${VSTSDK_PATH}/public.sdk/source/vst2.x/audioeffectx.cpp
    ${VSTSDK_PATH}/public.sdk/source/vst2.x/audioeffect.cpp
    ${VSTSDK_PATH}/public.sdk/source/vst2.x/vstplugmain.cpp
)

SET(VSTSDK_HOST_SOURCE
    ${VSTSDK_PATH}/pluginterfaces/vst2.x/aeffectx.cpp
)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set what to compile how
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET(GIJZELIJZER_SOURCE
    src/gijzelijzer.cpp
    src/gijzelijzer.h
    src/gijzelijzermain.cpp
    resources/gijzelijzer.rc
    resources/vstplug.def
    ${VSTSDK_PLUGIN_SOURCE}
)

ADD_LIBRARY(gijzelijzer SHARED ${GIJZELIJZER_SOURCE})

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Include 3rd party library headers
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${VSTSDK_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Link libraries
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gijzelijzer
    ${VSTSDK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: Yes, variable `VSTSDK_INCLUDE_DIR` is not defined in the given `CMakeLists.txt`. Possibly, the author forgets to define it, or he intends that user passes this variable via cmake definitions.

Comment: Note that undefined variables in CMake expand to the empty string. So in this case, the call to `target_link_libraries` will simply do nothing, which might or might not have been the intended behavior.